# Error while importing tensorflow as tf on Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, pip, google-colaboratory

I had been using a simple "import tensorflow as tf" command to import tensorflow on my Colab notebook for months. However, just recently the same code and notebooks started giving me the error "**from **future** imports must occur at the beginning of the file**".

The tensorflow package version I found on using "!pip list" was "2.8.2+zzzcolab20220719082949".

The main thing confusing me is how a notebook/code that was working perfectly 2 weeks back suddenly starts giving errors.

The code for the cell I ran which gave this error was:

```
import sys
from tflite_model_maker import image_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import DataLoader
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import EfficientNetLite0Spec
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import EfficientNetLite4Spec
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import tensorflow as tf
```

The error I got was -

> File "", line 9
> import tensorflow as tf
> ^
> SyntaxError: from **future** imports must occur at the beginning of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to move your `__future__` import at the top of your code to make it work:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import sys
from tflite_model_maker import image_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import DataLoader
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import EfficientNetLite0Spec
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import EfficientNetLite4Spec

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import tensorflow as tf
```

Please have a look at the [future-statements docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements):

> A future statement must appear near the top of the module. The only
> lines that can appear before a future statement are:
>
> - the module docstring (if any),
> - comments,
> - blank lines, and
> - other future statements.

In your case you have other imports before your `__future__`, which is not allowed.